# Performance of DeepClone (using binary serialization) versus manually setting properties

Tags: c#, performance, clone

I have a collection of objects and I am trying to clone this collection and trying to understand performance implication of different approaches.

The object in the collection has about 20 properties all strings, ints, floats (this objects doesn't have any nested objects inside of it).   The two approaches are:

1. Create DeepClone() method:

   ```
   public static class ExtensionMethods
   {
       public static T DeepClone<T>(this T a)
       {
          using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
          {
              var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
              formatter.Serialize(stream, a);
              stream.Position = 0;
             return (T)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
          }
      }
   ```

   }
2. Manually write "copy" code where i am looping through the collection and "new"ing a new object and then manually setting all of the 20 properties.  something like this

   ```
    public MyObject Copy(MyObject myObj)
   {
    var obj = new MyObject();
    obj.Prop1 = myObj.Prop1;
    obj.Prop2 = myObj.Prop2;
    return obj;
   ```

   }

I am getting very inconsistent results so I wanted to get peoples feedback on:

1. Should one be much faster that the other?  I would have thought choice two but my tests don't seem to support this so I am trying to figure out if I am doing something wrong.
2. Is there any way to do this even faster?

Comment: I'm not sure why you've labeled this DeepClone(), when you only want to perform shallow copying. Since strings are immutable, a shallow copy of a string is equivalent to a deep copy. In addition, manually setting must be much faster since BinaryFormatter uses reflection to get property names, setters, constructors, etc.

Comment: @Gelno - this method would deep Clone the object if it had nested objects inside of it (thus the name)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, first of all BinaryFormatter route must definitely be slower, since it uses reflection to get/set properties. The most common method is using the IClonable interface in conjunction with a copy constructor.

```
class A : ICloneable
{
    private readonly int _member;

    public A(int member)
    {
        _member = member;
    }

    public A(A a)
    {
        _member = a._member;
    }

    public object Clone()
    {
        return new A(this);
    }
}
```

Of course strictly speaking you only need the copy constructor, which should be the fastest method. If your objects are simple, you should try using in-built [MemberwiseClone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone.aspx) function.

```
class A : ICloneable
{
    private readonly int _member;

    public A(int member)
    {
        _member = member;
    }

    public object Clone()
    {
        return MemberwiseClone();
    }
}
```

Meanwhile, I wrote [some test code](http://codepaste.net/wcp4nc) to see if MemberwiseClone() was severely faster or slower than using a copy constructor. You can find it [here](http://codepaste.net/wcp4nc).  I found that MemberwiseClone is actually much slower than doing a CopyConstructor, at least on small classes. Note that using the BinaryFormatter is insanely slow.

Comment: Doesn't MemberwiseClone use reflection? Or is it just a memcpy, and the GC doesn't need any further assistance?

Comment: I think it uses some CLR hooks to get performance, so basically memcpy and a few adjustments.

Comment: As in the help for MemberwiseClone it is mentioned that it makes a shallow copy could it be the same as using BinaryFormatter? I am doubtful because the that function is named DeepCopy, which I guess the name is incorrect. My point is that deep clone should clone the referenced objects as well???

Comment: @Sam - this method is generic and used other places but if there were nested objects it would clone them as well

Comment: @Sam, the OP specified DeepCopy in title, but then mentioned that he only has shallow objects to copy, so MemberwiseClone() is much more efficient than BinaryFormatter.

Comment: As an aside: use of the Clone method is not recommended in the framework guidelines these days, due to the fact it is not clear whether it is a shallow clone or deep clone. It would be recommended to create a new interface, e.g. IDeepCloneable or IShallowCloneable to implement your two examples above, as the behaviour would be clear.

Comment: @Rob, worse still it's not generic; and if you want to clone you almost always have to do an ugly cast.

Comment: @Gleno - Yes - indeed. In fact, I should have said it is recommended to implement IDeepCloneable<T> (which inherits a non-generic IDeepCloneable). This is what I've tended to do when a deep clone is needed.

Answer (score 2):

In my previous role, we investigated this very issue, as we were caching objects and wanted to clone them before handing them out from the cache.

We did some detailed benchmarking and found that property setting was always *at least an order of magnitude faster* then the `BinaryFormatter` approach, although obviously required a hand-rolled implementation as opposed to the much simpler `BinaryFormatter` approach. For deep object graphs, the difference became more pronounced IIRC.

In the end, we settled on a three pronged approach to "cloning":

- if the type was immutable (which we would signify with a marker interface, `IImutable`, but you could equally use an attribute or somesuch), we would "clone" by returning the original instance. Since we knew no-one could mutate it, it was safe to keep returning the same instance. Obviously this was the fastest type of "clone", although clearly not really a clone at all.
- If the type implemented our own `IDeepCloneable<T>` interface (which would be like your second example - but generic) we'd use that. [This generic interface would inherit from a non-generic equivalent `IDeepCloneable`]
- Failing that, we'd fall back to your first example, the `BinaryFormatter`.

I mention the "immutable" approach because depending on what you are doing, sometimes the best way is to redesign the classes you need to clone so they don't need to be cloned at all. If they are essentially read-only once created, this is easy; but even if not, sometimes the builder/immutable-type approach is useful (see `Uri` vs. `UriBuilder` in the framework. The former is essentially immutable, while the latter can be used to build and/or mutate instances of the former).

Answer (score 0):

Using serialization for that is a very clever idea. However, setting the properties one by one should be just as fast, and most of the time (except when the objects are really small)  must faster - you're doing less work, and not using reflection.

Can you reproduce a case where using serialization was faster than copying the properties 'by hand'?

Answer (score 0):

Serialization is be definitely slower then just property assignment.

Binary serialization is preferable, cause the code is easy and easy to maintain.

The property assignment, instead, is better cause may be during the clone, you don't want to clone **all** properties of the object, but want to be able to serialize them by the way. In short you have more a control on the flow.